# How to insert text into TextBox at cursor point?

Tags: vb6, textbox, cursor

How can you insert text into a `TextBox` at the current cursor position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text can be inserted at the current cursor position of a `TextBox` by setting `SelText` to a string:

```
TextBox1.SelText = "text to be inserted"
```

Comment: Obviously I read your question thoroughly; just quick blink. But I think I gave you an idea as on what to search for ... All the time I was thinking you needed cursor position only... :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your text box is named: `txtTitle`:

```
With txtTitle
   .SelStart = .SelLength 'SelStart will place cursor at the last selected character
End With
```

Example:

```
txtTitle.SelStart = 7 'This will place cursor after 7th character
```

**EDIT:**
Just for the clarification: SelLength will return 0 if no character has been selected and than you can use SelStart to get current position. This is what you should test:

```
Dim iPos As Long
With txtTitle
  If .SelLength = 0 Then
    iPos = .SelStart
  Else
    iPos = .SelStart + .SelLength
  End If
  Debug.Print "The current cursor position in " & .Name & " is: " & iPos & " :-)"
End With
```

Comment: I don't need to determine the current cursor position. I want to be able insert text programmatically at the current position. I need the equivalent of .NET's `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(currentPosition, insertText);`

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is paste text at the current cursor location then do the following.

text1.seltext = "here's some text I'm pasting in"
text1_click

The code above will paste your text at the current cursor position and then place the cursor at the end of the pasted text.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this site isn't letting me finish my code entry. Using my example will insert the text but it will be selected text after pasting it. To deselect the text and leave the cursor at the end of the pasted text you have to call a textbox1 click event like this. text1[underscore]click.